# nvm messed up my global module installation location, how do I fix it?

Tags: node.js, nvm

I run `npm install -g pm2` but when I run pm2, I hit the error:

> zsh: command not found: pm2

I checked `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` found pm2 was not there.

I run `npm list -g` and found pm2 was installed at `/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules`

But I had deleted nvm a long time ago by running `rm -fr /Users/langqiu/.nvm/` & deleted what nvm added to my ~/.bash_profile

I installed nvm again then run the following command, but npm -g still installed at wrong place.

What can I do fix it ?

```
☁  ~  nvm ls
        v8.14.0
->       system
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> v8.14.0) (default)
stable -> 8.14 (-> v8.14.0) (default)
nvm_list_aliases:36: no matches found: /Users/langqiu/.nvm/alias/lts/*
☁  ~  nvm use system
Now using system version of node: v12.13.0 (npm v6.12.0)
☁  ~  npm install -g pm2
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2 -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2-docker -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2-runtime -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2-dev -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev
+ pm2@4.1.2
updated 1 package in 7.938s
☁  ~  which pm2
pm2 not found
```

I did these, but it still didn't fix the problem

```
☁  ~  npm config --global set prefix /usr/local
☁  ~  npm install -g pm2
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2-dev -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-dev
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2 -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2-docker -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-docker
/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/bin/pm2-runtime -> /Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0/lib/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2-runtime
+ pm2@4.1.2
☁  ~  pm2
zsh: command not found: pm2
```

--- update ----

With the answer I got I finally fix it. It is b/c of ~/.npmrc setting

```
☁  ~  cat ~/.npmrc
registry=https://registry.npm.taobao.org/
prefix=/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0
```

But why running `npm config --global set prefix /usr/local` did not fix that ?

Answer (score 2):

Per [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders), simply `npm config --global set prefix /usr/local`

Comment: Seems like you still have nvm installed? Check `which npm` before running, nvm ignores the configured prefix.

Comment: I said in my question that in order to fix it I reinstalled nvm (please check my question for detailed information). My npm is at /usr/local/bin/npm

Comment: I saw, but you won't be able to install anything globally while nvm is installed: it completely bypasses the prefix config. You'll need to fully uninstall it again (removing any latent commands in bashrc and profile and restarting your shell as well) before continuing to install things in the proper global directory

Comment: OK I found the reason! In my ~/.npmrc it set prefix=/Users/langqiu/.nvm/versions/node/v8.14.0. So even though I have uninstalled nvm it still causes the problem. Man I hate nvm.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: But why running npm config --global set prefix /usr/local did not fix that ?

Comment: Perhaps because of the global switch. Run locally it may have resolved it.

Comment: I suppose that you run nvm without uninstalling another node.js?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem by adding a new version of node.

Here's my workflow for reference:

The problem:

```
$ nvm ls

->       system
iojs -> N/A (default)
node -> stable (-> N/A) (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
nvm_list_aliases:36: no matches found: ~/.nvm/alias/lts/*
```

Add the latest npm version

```
$ nvm install-latest-npm
Downloading and installing node v6.14.4...
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.14.4/node-v6.14.4-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Computing checksum with sha256sum
Checksums matched!
Now using node v6.14.4 (npm v3.10.10)
Creating default alias: default -> v6.14.4
```

Set the node version:

```
$ nvm use default
Now using node v6.14.4 (npm v3.10.10)
```

Test I'm now using the latest version of node:

```
$nvm current
v6.14.4
```

Test the solution worked:

```
$ nvm ls
->      v6.14.4
         system
default -> v6.14.4
node -> stable (-> v6.14.4) (default)
stable -> 6.14 (-> v6.14.4) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
unstable -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/erbium (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.17.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.17.0 (-> N/A)
lts/dubnium -> v10.21.0 (-> N/A)
lts/erbium -> v12.18.1 (-> N/A)
```